# Got an error "ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED" when creating a new instance on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Recently I created a number of GPU instances on Google Cloud across 5 regions.

However when I tried to create more than a number of instances in one region, I got an error `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED`.

I googled about the error, and found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/nV1Ym57OCj8) mentioned about it's a resource limit on the corresponding region.

I wonder if it's actually a quota limit per user account or project, or  the only way is to wait for other users to release their resources ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you see 'ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED' error meaning you are encountered with the temporary resource stock-out issue at that particular zone. I would like to point you to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/asJA71NDkZM/2qon8TQZBQAJ) made by "Paul Nash", who thoroughly explained the resource stock-out issue at Google Cloud Platform (GCP). The recommended workaround is to try a different zone or later if you are looking to get resources in the same zone as those issues are to be expected transiently.

This is apparently not a Quota issue and if you encounter any Quota issue then you should get an error related to "Quota Exceed".

Comment: However, after I deleted 1 stopped GPU instances out of around 300 across 5 regions, I could create 1 instance again. It feels like the stopped instances will affect how I claim new resources too ?

Comment: If you stopped an instance, it is still reserving the resources you have used to spin up that particular instance such as CPU, GPU, Disk and so on. You can claim your already used quota only if you delete it. Deleting will release the resources used.