# Is it possible to get GCP's ANY distribution for Kubernetes GKE node pool?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, availability-zone

I have a GKE Kubernetes cluster running on GCP. This cluster has multiple node pools set with autoscale ON and placed at us-central1-f.

Today we started getting a lot of errors on these Node pools' Managed Instance Groups saying that us-central1-f had run out of resources. The specific error: ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS

I've found [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586941/got-an-error-zone-resource-pool-exhausted-when-creating-a-new-instance-on-goog) on Stackoverflow with a similar question, where the answer points to a discussion on Google Groups with more details. I know that one of the recommended ways of avoiding this is to use multiple zones and/or regions.

When I first faced this issue I wondered if there is a way to set multiple region as a fallback system, instead of redundancy system. In that sense, I would set my VMs to be placed wherever zone that has available resources prioritizing the ones closer to, lets say, us-central1-f.

Then, reading the discussion on the Google Group I found a feature that caught my attentions which is the ANY distribution method for Managed Instance Groups. It seems that this feature does exactly what I need - the zone fallback.

So, my question: Does the ANY distribution method resolve my issue? Can I use it for GKE Node Pools? If not, is there any other solution other than using multiple zones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get a regional (i.e. multi-zonal) GKE deployment, however this will use multiple zonal MIGs as the underlying compute layer. So technically speaking you will not use the ANY distribution method, but you should achieve pretty much the same result.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I thought that having multi-zonal node pools meant that each node pool would always have an instance. But it turnout if you set scale down to 0 many times only one zone will have a node while the others wont't have any. That's what I wanted.